# Laravel : Saving empty string in database even if it's not empty input in form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

**When I type in my registration form  in app name,email,and phone the phone is not displayed and the sting are saved in strange format.**

**When I run `php artisan tinker:`**

```
 DB::table('user1s')->get();
=> [
     {#640
       +"id": 1,
       +"name": """
         \x09
         \x09sda\t
         """,
       +"email": """
         \x09
         \x09sds\t
         """,
       +"phone_number": "",
       +"created_at": "2016-07-02 11:28:04",
       +"updated_at": "2016-07-02 11:28:04",
     },
     {#642
       +"id": 2,
       +"name": """
         \x09
         \x09da
         """,
       +"email": """
         sd\x09
         \x09
         """,
       +"phone_number": "",
       +"created_at": "2016-07-02 11:33:56",
       +"updated_at": "2016-07-02 11:33:56",
     },
     {#643
       +"id": 3,
       +"name": """
         more in-\x0D
         \x09
         """,
       +"email": """
         \x09
         \x09more in-
         """,
       +"phone_number": "",
       +"created_at": "2016-07-02 11:52:43",
       +"updated_at": "2016-07-02 11:52:43",
     },
   ]
```

My form in the view looks like:

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <h1>    Welcome please register!    </h1>

    <h1>All users</h1>

     @foreach ($user1s as $user1)
        <div>
            {{ $user1->phone_number }}
        </div>

    @endforeach 

        <hr>
        <h3>Fill in required informations</h3>

        <form  method="POST" action=" "> 
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>


            <ul class="list-group" >

                Name
                <div class="form-group" title="name" >
                    <textarea name="name" class="form-control" ></textarea>
                </div>


                Email
                <div class="form-group"  title="email"> 
                    <textarea name="email"  class="form-control" ></textarea>
                </div>

                Phone number    
                <div class="form-group"  title="phone_number"> 
                    <textarea name="phone_number"  class="form-control" ></textarea>
                </div>


                    <div class="form-group" >
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </div>

            </ul>
        </form>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

And my migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user1s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string("name");
        $table->string("email");
        $table->string("phone_number");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Somebody sees the problem?

Comment: Need to see your controller, really. That's the part that does the logic.

Comment: Oh,It's clear now i didn't save the phone number:  public function store(Request $request)
    {  
      $this->validate($request , [
       'name' =>'required' ,
       'email' =>'required' ,
       'phone_number' =>'required' , 
       ]);
  
         $user= new User1;
      $user->name = $request->name;
      $user->email =  $request->email;
      $user->save();

     return redirect('/thankyou');

    }
}

Comment: @Farkie thanks! But the only thing that's confusing is the   \x09 by the string?

Comment: x09 is a tab character.. maybe you have a tab character set in the textarea box?

Comment: Yes ,I thing i have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here lies in your Controller (or end route) code. As said in the comments, you've missed out saving of the `phone_number` item.